# ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: database "aquastarsbackend_development" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When trying to run rails db:migrate I am getting the error above.  Now I am positive I have postgres running and have the following code in the database.yml file.

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode

# For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
username: briankaty1
password: 

development:
<<: *default
database: aquastarsbackend_development
```

I have not setup a password.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running `rails db:create`?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterZhu that seems to have worked.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is in the comments. OP did not create the database (by `rails db:create`) before running migrations.